# Jmeter Selenium Integration Using Selenium Jars 3.3

Tags: selenium, jmeter

I want to integrate Jmeter with selenium 3.3. I have succesfully integrated Jmeter with  Selenium Using Selenium 2.53 Jars and it works fine for me,But I am unable to integrate Jmeter with selenium using Selenium jars 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple process:

1. Download [Selenium Java Client libraries](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)
2. Unpack the archive and put the following libraries to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (it is enough to drop the jars to JMeter's "lib" folder and restart JMeter to pick them up)

   - `client-combined-x.x.x-nodeps.jar`
   - everything from `lib` folder
3. Once done you can develop Selenium-related code using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) or import existing tests using [JUnit Request sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter)